# How to fix whereNotExists and where query builder laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to combine whereNotExists and where, if you use it simultaneously it will and if you try one of them you can

```
    $query = DB::table('tabel_produk')->where('kode_customer',$cust)->whereNotExists(function($query){
$query->select(DB::raw(1))->from('tabel_detail_realisasi')->whereRaw('tabel_detail_realisasi.barcode = tabel_produk.barcode');
})->distinct()->orderBy('barcode','asc') ->get();
```

Pleae help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your DB schema so I've tried something similar with a local DB I have and it seems to be working fine. See my example below. Could you please replace my query with yours and see what's output by the query logger?

```
    DB::flushQueryLog();
    DB::enableQueryLog();
    $results = DB::table('product_templates')
        //Non deleted products
        ->where('deleted', '=', '0')
        //
        ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            //Where the category is not 'General'
            $query
                ->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('product_categories')
                ->whereRaw('product_categories.id = product_templates.category_id')
                ->where('product_categories.name', 'General');
        })
        ->distinct()
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
    DB::disableQueryLog();
    $queryLog = DB::getQueryLog();
    logger("Query results", compact('results', 'queryLog'));
```